# Sharepoint web analytics Reports permissions

Tags: permissions, web-analytics

My turn to ask a question. Is there any way to grant someone permissions to view the web analytics reports for Site collections without making them site owner/Full control on the site collection?

I want to give a person access to only view the reports and be able to do something else on the site (apart from normal viewing rights).

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to give a user rights to view web analytics without giving them other permissions, you need to:

1. Create a new Permission Level where the only permission is "View Web Analytics Data  -  View reports on Web site usage"
2. Create a new SharePoint group which you assign the newly created Permission level
3. Add the user to this group (either directly or preferably through an AD group)

Comment: Thanks Per. Works perfectly. Easiest 50 points you ever made :-) i can only hand it over tomorrow though.

Comment: does not work for SharePoint 2013